# Definition of linear eq in 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

In the standard maths textbook of class 9th & 10th in India, the definition given for linear eq in 2 variables is **eq of the type ax+by+c=0**; where a, b, c are real no's & **a&b are not both=0** i.e either a=0 or b=0. One of the examples given is: 2x=3, since it can be written in the form 2x+0y-3=0. Doesn't this definition complicate things. What could be the incentive in defining things this way. Why not put the condition a≠0 & b#0, since that leads to a visible demarcation between linear eq's having 2 variables vs 1 variable.

Comment: It's rather arbitrary, you are right. But ask yourself the question: why do you want to require any parameter to be non-zero? Wouldn't it be beautiful if linear equations in 2 variables encompass those in 1, and those in 1 those in 0? If one even argues which parameters should be forbidden to be zero, this hints to that none should be!

Comment: This generality might be more understandable for a teacher or parent, but when they teach kids, they start with linear eq's in 1 variable, describing it in a simple way, avoiding a general form & relying on examples (which reinforces the idea). Thus omitting the interpretation of 1 variable eq being a sub-case of 2 variable eq with one of the constants being zero. So it kind of messes up with their understanding, when this kind of definition is brought up.

Comment: I understand this reasoning, but what they are now doing is even a bigger mess. Because, what you ultimately want to do right after introducing linear eq in 2 variables is to say that you can add or subtract two such eqs and that this again results in a linear eq in 2 variables. And this statement is false in general except if linear eqs in 0 variables are linear eqs in 1 variable, linear eqs in 1 are linear eqs in 2, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, fortunately not many students go through the pains of reading and interpreting the fine print & specifics of definitions. Instead relying on their understanding obtained from solving examples, which in no way presents a completely accurate picture, but still better than getting your mind twisted through all the jargon.

Comment: If the fine print is anyway unimportant, I agree with you that one should require either that both $a$ and $b$ should be defined non-zero, or none. Only requiring one to be non-zero however makes no sense at all. It's not solving any problem as compared to requiring both to be non-zero, and only causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A system of two linear equations of the form
$$ax + by + c = 0$$
$$fx + gy + h = 0$$
can be valid even if one of the four coefficients is 0.
For instance, suppose $a = 0$. Then $y = \frac{-c}{b}$, which one can then plug into the second equation -
$$fx + g \left( \frac{-c}{b} \right) + h = 0$$
$$x = \frac{cg - bh}{bf}$$
Our solution to this system of equations, then, is
$$\left( \frac{cg - bh}{bf}, \frac{-c}{b} \right)$$

Comment: Yes. With the same argument, a system of 2 linear equations in 1 argument can be valid even if we don't require $a\neq 0$, take e.g. $0=0$ and $x=1$. Imo, the botton line is that requiring that we shouldn't require any coefficient to be non- zero at all.